# What exactly gets stored when referencing external contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, storage

Imagine two contracts, `A` and `B`

```
contract A{
    ...
}

contract B{
  A a;
  function B(address aAddr){
     a = A(aAddr);
  }
}
```

What exactly is `B` storing about contract `A`? Does it store function hashes? Does it store `A`'s bytecode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it creates an instance of A so it is using only a reference in other words B is storing the A's Address, no bytecode no hash.

try to debug the code and watch storage and memory changement.
in this exemple the A address is  : 0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27 aa97d1a86395877b3a

[image]